# Cast has killed me -?

Tags: linq, casting

```
 Error  4 Cannot implicitly convert type  
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CCE_2009.Data.Person>>'  
to  
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CCE_2009.Data.Person>'
```

Generated from:

```
var RecoveryManagerQuery =
    from RM in
    (
        from REP in e.Results
        select REP.Organization.Representatives.Select(RM=>RM.Person)
    )
    select RM;
RecoveryManagers = new ObservableCollection<Person>(RecoveryManagerQuery.ToList());
```

Why is this IEnumberable embeded - Organizations have one or more representatives where each representative is related to one and only one person.

I want a list of Persons that match this criteria.....

argghh..

R

Comment: Calm down, take a deep breath. Then you paste the whole error message and give a little more context about what e represents, is this LINQ2Objects or LINQ2SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer query is redundant. We can make this clearer by removing it:

```
var RecoveryManagerQuery =
    from REP in e.Results
    select REP.Organization.Representatives.Select(RM=>RM.Person);
```

As you can see, the `select` clause says, for each `REP`, to select all the people associated with representatives in `REP`'s organization. This means that each element in `RecoveryManagerQuery` is going to be a *set* of `Person` objects, not an *individual* object. You want to flatten the query so it returns a set of `Person` objects, not a set of a set of `Person` objects:

```
var RecoveryManagerQuery =
    from REP in e.Results
    from orgRep in REP.Organization.Representatives
    select orgRep.Person;
```

**Edit:** Here is the dot notation:

```
e.Results.SelectMany(
    REP => REP.Organization.Representatives,
    (REP, orgRep) => orgRep.Person);
```

Comment: I seein your example their is only one select, and hence, only one collection. How would you write this in dot notation?

var RecoveryManagerQuery = e.Results.Select(P => P.Organization.Representatives.Select(RM=>RM.Person)); but this too has two selects and generates the same error.. just curious at this point in time!

Comment: I got it to work this way - looks much more complicated than I think it should be:

e.Results.Select(P=>P.Organization.Representatives).SelectMany(Reps=>Reps.ToArray()).Select(Rep=>Rep.Person);

Comment: @codputer: I added the dot notation to my answer.

Comment: Never used SelectMany - but I think I know now how and when to use it.  Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? You are getting a IEnumerable of an IEnumerable because of the nested LINQ query.

Depending upon what you are trying to achieve, you could change your query to:

```
var RecoveryManagerQuery =
    from REP in e.Results
    select REP.Organization.Representatives.Select(RM=>RM.Person);
```

Comment: I tested this and it still returned an IEnumerable within an IEnumberable... which I think now makes sense to me as their are two selects hence the two collections... see answer to avoid the double select